# Spring oauth2 SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler two redirects on failure

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

For some reason spring with oauth2 and custom SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler redirects twice on login failure.

It calls http://localhost:8081/login?error as expected but with a location header http://localhost:8081/login therefore I see an extra redirect.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    http.requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/login",  "/oauth/authorize")
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/" + URLConstants.LOGIN)
            .loginProcessingUrl("/" + URLConstants.LOGIN)
            //.failureUrl("/login?error")
            .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
            .permitAll();
```

And SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler

```
@Component
public class AuthFailureHandler extends 
SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // some code
    saveException(request, exception);
    getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response,  "/login?error");
```

Above code onAuthenticationFailure pretty much calls same methods as original code in onAuthenticationFailure. I've also tried 
    super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
But I do get same results (an extra redirect)

If I remove .failureHandler(authFailureHandler) then the code works as expected. Any ideas?

See images attached
Extra redirect - with SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler
[image: Extra redirect - with SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler]
As expected - without SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler
[image: As expected - without SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler]